# Read campaign information from Google Analytics (Universal)

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

During the `ga.js` days I used to read the campaign information by parsing the `_u**` cookies. Now in Universal Analytics `analytics.js` it seems that google is storing only the user id in `_ga` cookie.

So is there anyway now to read campaign information (like campaign name, source etc) that are passed through `utm_*` keys in the url?

I went through almost the entire documentation of Universal Analytics and there are only `set` and `send` available in trackers and no `get` methods.